# Just installed 15.04 I am receiving the following messages at the end of my terminal command: sudo apt-get update

Tags: upgrade, 15.04

```
Fetched 331 kB in 11s (28.6 kB/s)                                                                                                  
W: Failed to fetch 
extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/vivid/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/vivid/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found"
```

Plus one other Failed to fetch

```
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this is that those repositories haven't yet been created, for whatever reason. Once they are created, they will only contain extras, but if you want these extras now, you can add the 14.10 extra repos. Comment on this answer if you want to know how. I'll add it in.

Comment: OK thanks.  I'm OK waiting for them to be created, thought I was missing something from the update.